# how to prevent XXE attack using java 1.6

Tags: java, xxe

How can I prevent XXE attack using Java 1.6? Most examples that I googled are using Java 1.7. We need to stick to Java 1.6 for the moment.

Comment: May I ask why you NEED java 1.6?

Comment: Well, Oracles public support for Java 6 ended 2013, extended Support for Java SE 6 ends in December, which would increase security risk ... I would suggest the customer to switch to a newer version of Java.

Comment: I mean, java 6 was released 12 years ago, the free public updates ended on 2013 and the extended support ends in a month. Even java 7 is way behind on free updates.